# How to use "ddev import-db" and specify the path/file to import

Tags: docker, ddev

I started working with Docker and need to set-up a website project. I also need to import the database via command `ddev import-db --file=dumpfile.sql.gz`

but where do I need to put this dumpfile.sql.gz file? I tried putting it in root folder of project but after running the above mentioned command, I get this error:

```
Failed to import database db for webproject: Unable to validate import asset dumpfile.sql.gz: invalid asset: file not found
```

Sorry if maybe I'm missing some key concept understanding about Docker and import of files, but I don't understand the issue and googling this error (even parts of the error) returns absolutely no troubleshooting results.

Comment: Can you use a volume?

Comment: If you're running `ddev import-db ...` inside the container, then the `dumpfile.sql.gz` also needs to be available inside the container. You can expose it using a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In older ddev versions is "src" instead of "file". Thus, for instance in ddev 19.2:

ddev import-db --src=./dumpfile.sql.gz

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers. Also, `--src` is deprecated

Comment: @NicoHaase Answer updated. IMHO, it is not duplicated because not everybody is using the last ddev version.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to know anything about docker to use `ddev import-db`, and there are many examples if you use `ddev import-db -h`.

`ddev import-db` runs on your workstation, not inside the container. And the file you want to import is also on your workstation.

But the important thing you're missing is that you need a path or relative path to the file. So if the file is in /tmp, it would be

`ddev import-db --file=/tmp/db.sql.gz`

If the file is in a relative directory to where you're running the command, for example, if it's in a directory named "dumps" that is a subdirectory of your current directory, then

`ddev import-db --file=./dumps/db.sql.gz`

or

`ddev import-db --file=dumps/db.sql.gz`

This is just all about giving the command a way to find the file.

Examples from `ddev import-db -h`:

```
Examples:
ddev import-db
ddev import-db --file=.tarballs/junk.sql
ddev import-db --file=.tarballs/junk.sql.gz
ddev import-db --database=newdb --file=.tarballs/db.sql.gz
ddev import-db --file=.tarballs/db.sql.bz2
ddev import-db --file=.tarballs/db.sql.xz
ddev import-db <db.sql
ddev import-db someproject <db.sql
gzip -dc db.sql.gz | ddev import-db
```

From the docs:

- [import-db doc](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/commands/#import-db)
- [Database management](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/database-management/#database-management)

Comment: `--src` is deprecated, use `--file` instead.

Comment: Thanks @AlenSimonyan I updated it with current usage.

Comment: Confirmed this works January 3rd 2024